# Symfony2 - subquery within a join error

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, inner-join

I would like to use a subquery inside a join, however Symfony2 throws the following error:
[image]

Here is my failed attempt:

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT
              sc.id AS id,
              u.id AS userId,
              u.username AS username,
              sc_count.upvotes
            FROM
              myBundle:SuggestedCar sc
              INNER JOIN myBundle:User u WITH sc.user_id = u.id
              INNER JOIN (  SELECT sc1.user_id, COUNT(sc1.id) AS upvotes
                            FROM myBundle:SuggestedCar sc1
                            GROUP BY sc1.user_id
                ) sc_count WITH u.id = sc_count.user_id'
        );
```

Basically I'm just joining 3 tables and the third one has a count. The query worked when executing it inside the database.

How would it be possible to use a SELECT statement inside a join? Is it a good idea to use raw SQL at this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$em->createQuery()` function is expecting DQL as the parameter, not SQL.  If you want to execute a raw SQL statement, the syntax is different.  You can do it like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table";
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

for more on DQL or querying for objects, see [Querying for Object](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects).  The biggest difference is DQL will return an object (based on your entity classes in Symfony).  The method I posted above will just give you a PDO result.  So if you execute raw SQL, don't expect to be able to use the result as an object.

If you want to use raw SQL and still have the result mapped to an object, you can look at the doctrine docs about [Result set mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html).  In my opinion, this is more work than necessary.

Comment: Thanks, clearly I was mixing up the two! Now I'm using raw SQL for this problem.

Do you know how I could get the name of a joining table from within a controller/repository? It doesn't form a separate entity, because it represents a many-to-many relationship. I'd not like to hardcode the name of that table.

Comment: Do you mean you would like to use Symfony to generate that table in the database, and that's the table you want to set the name? I don't quite understand what you are asking.

Comment: Since I'm writing raw SQL, I wouldn't like to hardcode the table names. Getting the table names of e.g. User and Role is fine, but what if I want their joining table's name which is "user_role"? This joining table represents the many-to-many relationship between the two tables. Do you know how I could get its name?

Comment: you are the one that defines the table name in your entity class.  In your case, what is the problem with hardcoding the name? If you want to use raw SQL, that's usually what you need to do.

Comment: I just wanted to avoid changing the raw sql in case only the name of the table is changed. I might post the following as a separate question so that people can officially answer it. I woudn't like to use raw sql, but that seemed to be the only option when writing this query: http://i.gyazo.com/5cba14e3df200e4ce95e8e33896b8364.png Basically I'm counting entries in a many-to-many relation.